# Ionic web intent failing SDK 30+?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor, capacitor-plugin, webintents

While sharing web-intent from one ionic capacitor app to another ionic capacitor app using https://github.com/darryncampbell/darryncampbell-cordova-plugin-intent/
for SDK 30 and above it is throwing "Error" without any other explanation. Please find sample code in comments

**Steps to reproduce:**
Download the code base in comment, build app for  : -

varable gradle file  :-

````
  compileSdkVersion = 32
  targetSdkVersion = 32
  androidxActivityVersion = '1.2.0'
  androidxAppCompatVersion = '1.2.0'
  androidxCoordinatorLayoutVersion = '1.1.0'
  androidxCoreVersion = '1.3.2'
  androidxFragmentVersion = '1.3.0'
  coreSplashScreenVersion = '1.0.0-rc01'
  androidxWebkitVersion = '1.4.0'
  junitVersion = '4.13.1'
  androidxJunitVersion = '1.1.2'
  androidxEspressoCoreVersion = '3.3.0'
  cordovaAndroidVersion = '7.0.0'```


Android Manifest file :- 
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="io.ionic.starter">

<permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />

<queries>

  <package android:name="com.gameplay.app1" />
  <package android:name="com.google.android.apps.youtube" />
  <package android:name="com.google.android.youtube" />
  <package android:name="com.android.twitter" />
  <package android:name="com.flipkart.android" />
  <package android:name="com.google.android.apps.youtube.music" />
  <package android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps" />
      <package android:name="com.google.android.gm" />
      <package android:name="com.facebook.katana" />
      <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
      </intent>
      <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />
      </intent>
      <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
      </intent>
    </queries>


  <application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:supportsRtl="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

      <activity
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
          android:name="io.ionic.starter.MainActivity"
          android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
          android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch"
          android:launchMode="singleTask"
          android:exported="true">

          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.darryncampbell.cordova.plugin.intent.ACTION"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
          </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent-filter>

      </activity>

      <provider
          android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
          android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
          android:exported="false"
          android:grantUriPermissions="true">
          <meta-data
              android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
              android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
      </provider>
  </application>

  <!-- Permissions -->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LAUNCH_MULTI_PANE_SETTINGS_DEEP_LINK"/>

</manifest>
````

**Related Sample code:**

```
 const options = {
            action: this.webIntent.ACTION_VIEW,
            url: 'http://www.google.com'
        };
        this.webIntent.startActivity(options).then(
        intent => { console.log('Web Intent was successful', intent); },
        error => { console.log('Error, Web Intent failed', error);
        console.log('Error, Web Intent failed', error); });
```

Above code works & opens browser but  i am unable to open any app & send data to it, be it custom or google app eg : -

```
 const options: IntentOptions = {
      // action: this.webIntent.ACTION_SEND,
      component: {
        package: 'com.gameplay.app1',
        class: 'com.gameplay.app1.MainActivity'
      },
      extras: {
        launchingAppPackage: 'io.ionic.starter',
        launchingAppClass: 'io.ionic.starter.MainActivity'
      }
    };

    this.webIntent.startActivity(options).then(
      intent => { console.log('Web Intent was successful', intent); },
      error => { console.log('Error, Web Intent failed', error); }
    );
***
OR 
***
const options = {
                   action: this.webIntent.ACTION_SEND,
                   url: 'geo:23.5264055,148.1594006',
                   package: 'com.google.android.gms.maps'
                 };
                   this.webIntent.startActivity(options).then(
                     () => { console.log('Intent Launched'); },
                     (e) => { console.log('Intent Error', e); }
                     );
```

Comment: Sample code  at  (please remove space after :// )
https:// bit.ly/3aopyog

Comment: use this plugin: https://github.com/carsten-klaffke/send-intent

Comment: Hi @NajamUsSaqib do you have any sample code for sending & receiving text intents?

Comment: what you mean by sample code? example code is already in plugin repo.

Comment: i saw the example code, it is only for receiving the intent. I did not find example of sending the intent

Comment: i think you are looking for Share API. https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this issue, I upgraded to ionic 6 & sdk 33.
And in AndroidManifest.xml included the the  tag with the package names of the apps to which we need to share the intent